# npm ERR! Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'stdin') while run npm start

Tags: reactjs

I created an new react application using the command "npx create-react-app my-app --template typescript" and run the command after project created the following error displayed.
npm ERR! Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'stdin').
I have latest versions of nodejs(18.17) and npm(9.2).

Can anyone provide a solution to resolve this issue?

Comment: The latest version of Node.js is 20 https://nodejs.dev/en/about/releases/, and the latest version of npm is 9.8.1 https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v9.8.1.

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing the npm cache forcefully by executing the command: `npm cache clear --force`.

Delete the `node_modules` directory and the `package-lock.json` file

Once the cache is cleared and the unnecessary files are removed, reinstall the dependencies by running: `npm install`.